# Download file from dotnet Core Web API using POST in ASP.NET MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to download a file from dotnet Core Web API. The controller accepts POST requests and looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/pdf")]
    //[Consumes("application/octet-stream")]
    [Produces("application/pdf")]
    public IActionResult GetPDF([FromBody] ReportRequest request)
    {
       //report generation logic
       return new FileStreamResult(pdfMemoryStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**I'm not sure how to send a POST request from a ASP.NET MVC 5 controller to this dotnet core API controller**

I've tried `WebClient.UploadData(action, "POST", requestBytes);` where `requestBytes` is a byte array of the model obtained using `BinaryFormatter`, but the API controller rejects it saying `(406) Not Acceptable.`

This happens regardless of `[Consumes("application/octet-stream")]` on the API controller.

And there is no overload of `WebClient.UploadData` that allows POSTing JSON.

Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change GetPdf method to:

```
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult GetPDF([FromBody] ReportRequest request)
{
    //report generation logic
    return File(pdfMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
}
```

and use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://localhost:44398/api/values/GetPdf";
var reportRequest = new ReportRequest()
{
    Id = 1,
    Type = "Billing"
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportRequest);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Using this gave me the same 406 Not Acceptable status code.

Comment: In GetPdf  method try `return File(pdfMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");`

Comment: That did it! If you can add this comment to your original answer I would like to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I also had to decorate the GetPdf API action with `[Consumes("application/json")]` to use your code.